# Ionic / Cordova Plugin for querying the SSID and BSSID of the connected WiFi network without requesting location services

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ssid, ionic7

I am looking for a plugin for Ionic 7 to get the SSID and BSSID of the connected WiFi network. I was planning to use wifiwizard2, however it requires location services and with this I am running into issues with the app submission. Apple does not allow to use location services if they are not essential for the application. Getting SSID is not essential, but has huge impact on the UX on my app, so I was wondering if there are other ways to get the SSID and BSSID in Ionic without location services?